# DataTable from FileHelpers Class -- type.GetProperties() returns empty array

Tags: c#, .net, filehelpers

I've successfully pulled a CSV file into the following class:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreFirst(1)] // ignores first line of file, since it's a header
public class Employee {
    public string EmployeeId;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    // etc.
}
```

I need to create a DataTable based on that class in order to use SqlBulkCopy. I've found several examples, but the following method doesn't work for me:

```
private static DataTable createEmptyDataTable(Type myType) {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in myType.GetProperties()) {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

The problem is with myType.GetProperties().  It's not throwing an error, but it returns nothing. The PropertyInfo array that it should return is empty.  Been at this a while and can't figure out the problem...

EDIT:
I've also used this variant with no success:

```
private static DataTable createEmptyDataTable(Type myType) {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        PropertyInfo[] infoArray = myType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);

        foreach (PropertyInfo info in infoArray) {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(info.Name, info.PropertyType));
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by nothing?
an empty array?

Comment: that means you dont have any *public* properties. and as Dominic mentioned you have fields not properties

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your Employee class contains fields, not properties.  Use rather

```
myType.GetFields()
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that.  Good eye Dominic.

Answer (score 5):

When working with Properties : 
You need to specify the scope for the Get Properties, try this to return all property types : `GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static);`

When working with fields (i.e. no get/set), its similar, just a different function.  See :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for properties and not fields?  Try GetFields instead.

Comment: Thanks again, David.  Dominic barely beat you to the suggestion, so I gave him credit for the answer, but I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Yeah, he nailed the actual issue.  Good luck in all your developing journeys.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any properties in this class snippet. I use this code for Reference.cs classes from web services.

```
Employee objE = new Employee();
var members = objE.GetType().GetFields().Select(m => new
{
    Name = m.Name,
    MemType = m.MemberType,
    RtField = m.GetType(),
    Type = m.FieldType,
    MemAtt = m.GetCustomAttributes(true)
});
```